# How to change reported os version in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

**How to change reported os version in Windows XP?**
I need to know that because i want to run a newer game on Windows XP but it does not let me because minimum system requirement is Windows Vista.

Comment: And if game require some API functions, which are not avaible in Windows XP, you are out of luck, so please dont lie to the game. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I used [application verifier tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028).